# Installed app not showing on Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

I have a Samsung FGalaxy 7 using Android version 8.0.0.  I have an app that is on my list of apps to run (and it does run), but it does not show in Play Store so that I can uninstall it.  I tried finding it within Play Store, thinking that reinstalling it would clean up the app listings so I could uninstall it, but it looks like the app is no longer on there.

How can apps be uninstalled outside of Play Store?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running a newer version of Android you should be able to hold down on the app icon and then drag it to the top right of your screen where an "uninstall" should appear.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung does things differently , so you may need to vary it ; on stock you would   go to  Settings→ Apps & Notifications → App Info → scroll and find your app name → tap on it and you get to see details with uninstall option

[image]

Comment: This is on Oreo 8.0